# Problem factoring fifth degree polynomial in order to prove a summation equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^4=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}$$

Mostly unnecessary pretext:
In order to do this I have equated the sum of $k^5$ to the sum of $(k+1)5 -(n+1)^5$.
After using the binomial theorem to expand and then combine like terms you end up with...
1/6[6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n+6] and use that to determine that 6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n+6 = 30*sum(k^4)

The actual question I have:
I have tripled checked and verified with wolfram that this is the correct polynomial (6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n+6) and it should be able to factor into n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1).  I have been trying to long divide out the terms individually and I just keep ending up with remainders.  I am in calc 3 and still have never had any experience factoring polynomials of this degree and I am unsure if I am approaching it in the wrong way or not. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am at my wits end.

Note: this is for number theory but it is the factoring I am having trouble with so that is why I posted it with the tag algebra. Hopefully this is what I was supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a mistake in the polynomial to be factored.  It clearly isn't divisible by $n$.  In general start with checking easy factors, since after they are divided out, the biggest factor will be left by itself.

Comment: Something is not right. $n$ can't be a factor of the polynomial you've given, but $n$ is known to be a factor of the polynomial you're trying to calculate.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia article on Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: Could you show your triple-checked wolfram-alpha input?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980843/proof-of-a-summation-of-k4  I got started from this so my error may come from a bad word of advice her or my own err but it was (n+1)^5-10[(n(n+1)/2]-10[n(n+1)(2n+1)/6]-5[n(n+1)/2]-n=5sum(k^4) which I then expanded to get [6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n+6]/6=5sum(k^4) and then i multiplied both sides by six to get rid of the fraction and get my "30" ready on the other side of the equation.  I was hoping I just had to factor but I am now seeing the impossibility in factoring it so I must have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: I talked to my teacher about it earlier today after putting my question in and i think in my original expansion I should have a (n+1) instead of a one but I'm not sure I think my question was not understood 100 percent correctly but I also realize in the last equation i typed above if i didnt have that +6 in there it would be exactly what i need. I'm gonna go investigate it's origin. I shall post back.

Comment: so either it is from my expansion of (n+1)^5 or I am missing -1 in another expansion. I'm leaning towards the former.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was that my initial formula was flawed if I use (n+1)^5-1=sum(from 1 to n)of[(k+1)^5-k^5]

before I was using the sum from 0 to n that my teacher told me to which doesn't involve the -1 after the (n+1)^5.  Using the new formula above which I got from the wikipedia page Tim suggested had the -1 I needed due to the sum being from 1 to n.

I tried to word that as best as I could but math typing online is not my forte. Hopefully this can help someone else half as frustrated as me.