# The sum of powers $\sum_{k=0}^n k^4$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, alternative-proof

I would like to ask if anyone can explain to me how can I find the closed form of the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^n k^4$$ with the expansion contraction method of the sum

Like this example : $$Y_n=\sum_{k=0}^n k^2$$
Yet  another  way  to  discover  a  closed  form  for  Cl,  is  to  replace the  original  sum  by  a  seemingly  more  complicated  double  sum  that  can  actually  be simplified  if  we  massage  it  properly 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 =\sum_{0\le j \le k \le n } k= \sum_{0\le j \le n} \sum k=\sum_{0\le j \le n}\frac{(j+n)(n-j+1)}{2} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{0\le j \le n}(n(n+l)+j-j2)=  \frac{1}{2}n^2(n+1)+\frac{1}{4}n(n+1)-\frac{1}{2}Yn$$

Comment: @juniven Yes .Thank you for the edit.It was easy to deal with it with other methods like the repertoire method of by replacing the sum with an intergral.But the expansio contraction method it is too difficult to understand

Comment: What is the expansion contraction method? Google shows no results.

Comment: @OpenBall with this "name" is presented at the book "concrete mathematics second american publication" page 61

Comment: Well, for those of us who don't have access to that book, please define this method or give some example of how it works.

Comment: @OpenBall it is free to download it .I will try to bring the example

Comment: this means also that we prove the answer by induction

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close because you have received a couple of good answers but you still insist on a vaguely named method from a specific reference, which you have so far been unable to produce in detail. You cannot expect others to be familiar with that exact same book, and no one claims to be a mind reader here.

Comment: right now i try to right the example with the mathjax

Comment: Is it the [Graham–Knuth–Patashnik book](https://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025/)? As far as I can tell, the word “contraction” is never used in this book, and certainly not on page 61.

Comment: Might it be this method: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980843/proof-of-a-summation-of-k4?

Comment: @HansLundmark page 46 in the original version .I read a translated version

Comment: @HansLundmark this mehtod is the disturbance of the sum

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 =\sum_{0\le j \le k \le n } k^2$ already looks wrong to me.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I update it

Comment: OK, now we're talking! They call it “expand and contract”, to be precise.

Comment: Can't you just take the corresponding double sum of $k^3$, and then use the formula for $\sum k^3$ (which must be known in order for this method to work, it seems)?

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes i have tried it but a i had  problem handling the js and ns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach *via* linear maps:

**1.** $T:\mathbb{R}_5[x]\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}_5[x]},\quad T(p(x))=p(x+1)-p(x)$ is a linear map.

**2.**  The matricial equation of $T$ with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_5[x]$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}{y_1}\\{y_2}\\{y_3}\\{y_4}\\{y_5}\\{y_6}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{0}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}&{1}\\{0}&{0}&{2}&{3}&{4}&{5}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{3}&{6}&{10}\\ {0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{4}&{10}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{5}\\{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}&{0}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{x_1}\\{x_2}\\{x_3}\\{x_4}\\{x_5}\\{x_6}\end{bmatrix}\quad (*)$$

**3.** Using $(*)$ we get: $$T^{-1}(x^4)=\left\{{\alpha -x/30+x^3/3-x^4/2+x^5/5:\alpha \in{\mathbb{R}}}\right\}$$

**4.** Consider $h(x)\in{T^{-1}(x^4)}$ with $\alpha=0$. Then $T(h(x))=x^4$ i.e. $h(x+1)-h(x)=x^4$.

**5.** For $x=1,2,\ldots,n$ we get:
$$\begin{aligned}
&h(2)-h(1)=1^4\\
&h(3)-h(2)=2^4\\
&h(4)-h(3)=3^4\\
&\ldots\\
&h(n+1)-h(n)=n^4.
\end{aligned}$$

**6.** Simplifying: $h(n+1)-h(n)=1^4+2^4+\ldots+n^4=S_4$. That is
$$S_4=h(n+1)-h(1)=$$ $$-\displaystyle\frac{n+1}{30}+\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^3}{3}-\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^4}{2}+\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^5}{5}+\displaystyle\frac{1}{30}-\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}-\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}$$ $$=S_4=1^4+2^4+3^4+\ldots+n^4=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}.$$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}_5$?

Comment: @goblin $\Bbb R_n[x]$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le n$.

Comment: @OpenBall, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

We have $$
(k+1)^5-k^5 = 5 k^4 + 10 k^3 + 10 k^2 + 5 k + 1
$$
and so
$$
(n+1)^5=
\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)^5-\sum_{k=0}^nk^5 =\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n 5 k^4 + 10 k^3 + 10 k^2 + 5 k + 1 = 5 S_4 + 10 S_3 + 10 S_2 + 5 S_1 + S_0
$$
If you know the formulas for $S_3, S_2, S_1, S_0$, then you can solve for $S_4$.

Comment: this mehtod is the disturbance of the sum

Answer (score 2):

As $S_4(n)-S_4(n-1)=n^4$ is a quartic polynomial in $n$, $S_4(n)$ must be quintic.

You can obtain it as the Lagrangian interpolator of the six points

$$(0,0),(1,1),(2,17),(3,98),(4,354),(5,979).$$

The computation is quite laborious, but gives the correct

$$S_4(n)=\frac{n^5}5+\frac{n^4}2+\frac{n^3}3-\frac n{30}.$$

Comment: $S_4(n)$ must be quintic *if* you know that $S_4(n)$ must be a polynomial...

Comment: @lhf: what else could it be, when the first order difference is a polynomial ? (Note that it is easy to show the linear dependence of $S_0,S_1,\cdots S_d,n^{d+1}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_d(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n k^d$.

Then as $$k^d-(k-1)^d=dk^{d-1}-\binom d2k^{d-2}+\binom d3k^{d-3}-\cdots(-1)^d$$
we have
$$S_1(n)-S_1(n-1)=S_0(n)=n,$$
$$S_2(n)-S_2(n-1)=2S_1(n)-S_0=n^2,$$
$$S_3(n)-S_3(n-1)=3S_2(n)-3S_1(n)+S_0=n^3,$$
$$S_4(n)-S_4(n-1)=4S_3(n)-6S_2(n)+4S_1-S_0=n^4,$$
$$S_5(n)-S_5(n-1)=5S_4(n)-10S_3(n)+10S_2-5S_1+S_0=n^5.$$

Solving, we obtain

$$S_1(n)=\frac{n^2}2+\frac n2,$$
$$S_2(n)=\frac{n^3}3+\frac{n^2}2+\frac n6,$$
$$S_3(n)=\frac{n^4}4+\frac{n^3}2+\frac{n^2}4,$$
$$S_4(n)=\frac{n^5}5+\frac{n^4}2+\frac{n^3}3-\frac n{30}.$$